# Bootstrap responsive menu not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
   </nav>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Hi all...in the above bootstrap page the responsive menu not working properly...I am not able to find the error. can anybody help me on this. I tried by checking so many old questions in stack...but still the problem didn't resolved.

Comment: What is not running properly ? And what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 2):

There was a problem with JS file: instead of `bootstrap.min.js` I used `bootstrap.js`.

The issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `data-target=".nav-collapse"` by `data-target="#navbar"`

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/MxYzyrvuOA#

Comment: no...its not working...is there any problem with my JS files...when I am going to mobile size, the menu is in open mode by default...I mean the toggling is not happening...

Comment: Hey I got it...there is a problem with JS file...instead of "bootstrap.min.js" I used "bootstrap.js"...issue resolved...thanks for ur help.